# asp.net with javascript validation

Tags: asp.net

I want to do validation in asp.net with javascript on age and mobile number.  Can you suggest how I could do this?

Comment: belongs on sendmethecodez.com

Comment: New user -- cut him some slack.  Editing to remove offending "send me the codez" reference.

Comment: This isn't as stupid as you think, he may want to use the asp.net validators on the client side

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question please?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and the jQuery [validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) plugin which will handle these either directly or via the ability to extend the validation rules.  That's the code that I would use.

Answer (score 1):

For the age validation you can use a [RangeValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f70d09xt.aspx) and for the mobile number you can use a [RegularExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahwtc9e.aspx) validator.

Answer (score 0):

- For age you will want a validator that restricts the textbox to numbers only
- For mobile number, you will want numbers only, and also "+" and maybe "-"

I don't want to write a tutorial on validator controls here, but you'll need a [RangeValidator](http://www.w3schools.com/ASPNET/control_rangevalidator.asp)* for the age and a [RegularExpressionValidator](http://www.w3schools.com/ASPNET/control_regularexpvalidator.asp) with two regexes and a ValidationSummary control for the error messages. Set `EnableClientScript` on the two validators to true.

There's a large amount of [How Tos on the MSDN site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator.aspx).

<sub>* I suggested the wrong one there initially and copied George for RangeValidator</sub>